# Elasticsearch - not getting expected aggregated count

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

In a scenario, I have to search for phone numbers that start with '40'. I need to get a matching phone number that starts with '40' and a count of the phone number that is matching.

Actually, I want to search in multiple fields, just, for example, I am searching only for phone numbers.

For that, I used the below query.

```
GET emp_details_1_1/_msearch 
{
   "index":"emp_details_1_1"
}{
   "_source":[
      
   ],
   "size":0,
   "min_score":1,
   "query":{
      "multi_match":{
         "query":"40",
         "fields":[
            "phone"
         ],
         "type":"phrase_prefix"
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "phone":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"phone.keyword",
            "include":"40.*"
         }
      },
      "phone_count":{
         "value_count":{
            "field":"phone.keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am using Value Count aggregation for field-wise total count.

In the output, I can see the phone number data starting with '40', ie one single record. Example '40x-xxx-xxxx'
But When I see the count, the matching count is '4'. Because while aggregating the query is considering a phone number that starts with '40' and also a phone number that has '40' in between after the dash '-'. Example: 'xxx-40x-xxxx','xxx-xxx-40x','xxx-xxx-40x'. While getting the aggregate count, I want to omit the phone numbers that have '40' in between.

Below is the output, I am getting.

```
{
  "took" : 70,
  "responses" : [
    {
      "took" : 70,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 4,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [ ]
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "phone_count" : {
          "value" : 4
        },
        "phone" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "4034487929",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "status" : 200
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried various options, but not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of match_prefix query(which can be done only on text fields(analyzed)), you need to use the prefix query(done on keyword fields), good that you are already having the `keyword` field for your `phone` field, hence changing your query to below query will provide your correct results.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "min_score": 1,
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "phone.keyword": "40"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "phone": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "phone.keyword",
                 "include":"40.*"
            }
        },
        "phone_count": {
            "value_count": {
                "field": "phone.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And result

```
 "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "phone_count": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "phone": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "4034487929",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```